# how to make server return json not string (java.lang.IllegalStateException)

Tags: java, android, json

The API interface code in my Android client is:

```
import com.zift.myapplication88.models.ServerRequest;
import com.zift.myapplication88.models.ServerResponse;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface RequestInterface {
    @POST("learn2crack-login-register/")
    Call<ServerResponse> operation(@Body ServerRequest request);
}
```

I get the following error when I try to send data to server though:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

I don't know where to edit in my code so I can make server return `json` not `string`.

Comment: Could you paste the JSON you receive from the server?

Comment: This could also work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the Server side code for getting suggestions on making changes to your server side.
However, assuming that your server returns string (Which is a very bad practice), a workaround can be to write a custom converter for Retrofit.

Refer to [Retrofit with String response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170409/retrofit-with-string-response)