# Retrofit String response

Tags: gson, retrofit

An API Im making request on is returning a plain string (image url). Im using GSON with Retrofit.

This is the error message Retrofit is returning when Im making the request:

> Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

I added

```
.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
```

But then when app is started it crashes with this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lretrofit2/converter/scalars/ScalarsConverterFactory;
```

Im using the latest version of retrofit (2.9.0)

Does anyone have any idea why this would happen?

I tried this [Retrofit with String response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170409/retrofit-with-string-response)
I tried ScalarsConverterFactory

Comment: Could you please verify that there are no dependency exclusions configured which might omit the `com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars` artifact? If the cause of the `NoClassDefFoundError` is a `ClassNotFoundException` then most likely the classes of that dependency are omitted from your app for some reason. However, if the cause is a different exception type please add the complete stack trace to your question.

Comment: Could ProGuard rules have to do anything with this?

Comment: I don't think so; ProGuard (or R8) should notice that the class is used and not omit it. Though to be sure you can try to disable it and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Where are dependency exclusions configured? I tried searching for any kind of "converter-scalars" keyword trough the project and cant find anything

Comment: Maybe then try adding an explicit dependency on `converter-scalars`; though it is a bit weird that you can compile against it in the first place. You can also try [debugging the dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sec:listing_dependencies) to find out where `converter-scalars` is coming from (and why it might not be present in your app). This question and its answers might be useful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39008887